# SetWindowRgn freezes window

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

As the title says, I am having a problem with the window of an application freezing (not painting anymore) after I call SetWindowRgn. My source code is as follows:

```
    void MakeHole() 
    {
      // This will make a hole you can see through for the MainToon window.
      HRGN thisHgrn = CreateRectRgn(10, 200, 300, 200);
      SetWindowRgn(hwndClientList[intMainToon], thisHgrn, TRUE);
    }
```

I'm not even quite sure SetWindowRgn is the code I need to use. All I want to accomplish is a hole (transparent block) in a game window so that I can see through it. None of the other code in the project is really relevant at this point. Everything works as intended except that after I call SetWindowRgn, the game window doesn't draw anymore. It looks frozen but I can still close the window and the sound is still playing clearly. This is a visual C++ console application but I don't see how that could be of any importance either.
Let me know if you need anymore information.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code seems to be setting the whole window region rather than creating a hole. Your answer seems to do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem with the following code.

```
    void MakeHole()
    {
       // This will make a hole you can see through for the MainToon window.

       HRGN rgnOriginalWnd;
       HRGN rgnTheHole;
       HRGN rgnNewWnd;

       RECT rectDlg;
       GetWindowRect(hwndClientList[intMainToon], &rectDlg);

       rgnOriginalWnd = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, rectDlg.right - rectDlg.left, rectDlg.bottom - rectDlg.top);
       rgnTheHole = CreateRectRgn(10, 200, 350, 450);
       rgnNewWnd = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);

       CombineRgn(rgnNewWnd, rgnOriginalWnd, rgnTheHole, RGN_DIFF);
       SetWindowRgn(hwndClientList[intMainToon], rgnNewWnd, TRUE);

       DeleteObject(rgnOriginalWnd);
       DeleteObject(rgnTheHole);
       DeleteObject(rgnNewWnd);
    }
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but the documentation for SetWindowRgn clearly states you should no longer make function calls with the passed handle after calling it as it makes no clone. It also takes ownership of it, thus you're double deleting it

Comment: You should probably take a look at when this question was posted. To date, it was over 10 years ago.

Comment: I've seen that, but does it make it any less relevant for people looking at this post? For instance, I've found it after all this time while looking for answers to my problems